# How can I specify In condition cakephp save()?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455847/on-duplicate-key-update-in-cakephp)

> > INSERT INTO table1
> >        ('field1','field2','field1') 
> >        VALUES ('5','RENJITH','5','2012-08-04 15:07:38') 
> >        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'field4'='5'

How can I make it in cake php?

Comment: $this->Usertag->create();
      
      $this->data['Usertag']['user_id'] = $userId;
      $this->data['Usertag']['comment_id'] = $cmnt_id;
      $this->data['Usertag']['tag_name'] = $all_tag_arr[$i];
      
      $this->Usertag->save($this->data['Usertag']);