# 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

INSERT INTO table1
   ('id','name','cust_id','add') 
   VALUES ('5','RENJITH','5','2012-08-04 15:07:38') 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'cust_id'='5' WHERE 'table1.id' IN ('1','2','3')

> **make it in cakephp?**

Comment: Waht is uour model name in cakePHP ?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work in Model Class:

```
//check if key duplikates
$duplicate = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Model1.id' => 5)));

if($duplicate) {
  $this->updateALL(array('Model1.cust_id' =>5), array('Model1.id' => array(1,2,3)));
} else {
  $data['Model1'] = array('Model1.id' = 5, 'Model1.name' => 'RENJITH','Model1.cust_id' => 5, 'Model1.add' => strtotime('2012-08-04 15:07:38'));

  $this->create();
  $this->save($data);
}
```

Comment: For posterity, this answer is functionally similar and will often do the job, but it isn't the same as ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and it is two queries instead of one.  Also, unless you wrap it in a transaction, there is still a possibility of duplicate entries/errors if you're doing concurrent inserts.